# Error while calling a function

Tags: c, function, structure

On running this program i am getting error
     [Error] type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
on dev cpp  i am calling the function assign through main and i am getting the above mentioned error.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
void assign(struct username i);
 void show1(struct username i);
struct username
{
  char name[30];
  int rollno;
  float salary;
};
int main(void)
{
    struct username i;
    assign(i);
    show1(i);
} 


void assign(struct username i)
{
    puts("enter name");
    scanf("%s",i.name);

    puts("Enter roll no");
    scanf("%d",i.rollno);

    puts("Enter salary");
    scanf("%f",i.salary);
 }


  void show1(struct username i)
{
   printf("\n---------------------------------\n");
   printf("%s",i.name);
   printf("\n------%d-------\n",i.rollno);
   printf("%f",i.salary);
}
```

Comment: you have to move the definition of `struct username` above the function prototypes.

Comment: when calling the function: scanf() (and family of functions) always check the returned value ( not the resulting parameter value ) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this line: 'scanf("%s",i.name);' i.name is only 30 characters long and there is no limit in the "%s" input/conversion format id. So the user could easily overrun the i.name field, resulting in undefined behaviour, leading to a seg fault event. suggest: 'scanf("%29s", i.name)'  --or-- 'scanf("%" sizeof(i.name)-1 "s", i.name);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct username {
    char name[30];
    int rollno;
    float salary;
};

void assign(struct username *i);
void show1(struct username *i);

int main(void)
{
    struct username i;
    assign(&i);
    show1(&i);
}

void assign(struct username *i)
{
    puts("enter name");
    scanf("%s", i->name);

    puts("Enter roll no");
    scanf("%d", &i->rollno);

    puts("Enter salary");
    scanf("%f", &i->salary);
}

void show1(struct username *i)
{
    printf("\n---------------------------------\n");
    printf("%s", i->name);
    printf("\n------%d-------\n", i->rollno);
    printf("%f", i->salary);
}
```

I'm guessing that this is what you wanted. `scanf` requires pointer to some type and `struct` is passed by value into the function, so if you want to see the result in main you need to pass it by reference.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a function taking an argument with an, at that time, undeclared type because `struct username` is introduced into the scope **after** it's first usage.

Use a forward declaration or exchange the function declarations and the structure definition.

Answer (score -1):

Well, try using another IDE i would recommend like many others will do the code:blocks IDE, because i used dev cpp for a while and sometimes i have problems but when i run the code in another IDE it works just fine.
Try struct(username i);